# how to remove 'hints' from file manager Nautilus showing message about selected files and folders?

Tags: unity, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the tips within Nautilus 3.6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203936/how-to-remove-the-tips-within-nautilus-3-6)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and the default file manager is Nautilus 3.4.1.

One annoying thing is that it shows at the bottom of the display a message of which file or directory currently has the focus/selection on.

How can I remove this message? Here is a screen shot

[image]

Notice the yellow message at the bottom.

I tried Nautilus preferences, and do not see anything there. I tried Ubuntu own preferences and nothing there. I tried 'myUnity' configuration tool and see nothing there.

I select Ubuntu desktop when logging in as user. I assume this is the same as unity? I am using 12.04 LTS, just installed it.

thanks.