# How to remove the tips within Nautilus 3.6?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

New Nautilus version 3.6 (coming with Gnome 3.6 / Ubuntu 12.10) is showing annoying text tips on the bottom right/left edge as a new feature.

Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: This feature was available in 12.04 too. There is a bug filed for the same. Check out https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/958919

Comment: Never experienced it in 12.04... Moreover, I can't see "view" menu in the menu bar... I have just one menu called "Home folder".

Comment: The menu bar is now intergrated in the top panel on ubuntu, check there =)

Comment: I can see just "Home Folder" in the top panel, as already wrote.

Comment: Thanks for asking that questions. This tip box really sucks. I hope it will be configurable at same point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to remove the tip in the bottom left/right edges when you select a file or folder showing it's information.

This has been called *floating status bar* and the gnome developers wants to remove the old status bar also!! The old status bar is still available in 12.10. If you select from menu → *View* → *Status bar*, the old status bar will be activated and you will get rid of the new floating status bar. You can use this as a workaround.

There is a recent commit in nautilus source to remove the old status bar completely. The commit can be [seen here](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/src?h=gnome-3-6&id=676b96d2b7d91cc579bbac6e44d9aafc100e67a2). The main line of importance there is this two one:

> **Remove the statusbar**
>   We use a floating status bar now.

If you don't want this feature, I would suggest you to compile the nautilus yourself.

Comment: This would be a trick, if only I could see the view menu!!!

Comment: @jasmines if you don't see the menu, I think something is went wrong. You should try re-installing nautilus or testing 12.10 in Live mode if there is any *view* menu. I just verified that, there is a view menu there still.

Comment: As I wrote, I can see the menu, but the only one item I see is "Home Folder".

Comment: Purged gnome3 repo, reverted to quantal repo's official version. Menus are back and tips are gone. Thanks for your help, but I found out that nautilus 3.6 does NOT have menus.

Comment: Well, I have 12.10 installed and it has that menu. I think something from gnome3 repo caused this ..

Comment: It has that menu because it is NOT nautilus 3.6. Check your nautilus version with `sudo dpkg -p nautilus |grep -i version`

Comment: @jasmines Thanks. That was a somewhat small issue. glad to know you have fixed your problem by enabling the status bar option now. But anyway i think that nautilus is not in Ubuntu 12.10. it may have come with some repo

Answer (score 2):

Im using 10.10 . this should be similar to 12.04
open any folder in nautilus
Then click on `view`(top left corner) and disselect the status bar.
[image]
  In the top exaple u see that that statusbar is selected thus we seethe info of the file
[image]
  in this one we dont

thats it

Comment: does not work. Status bar was de-selected any way. Selecting it just changes the color of the message from yellow to black/white.  I think this hint is a global setting, not local to the file manager. I am noticing more hints in other apps. For example, with firefox, when I move the mouse near a tab at the top, I get a ballon hint. Like those one sees using windows file manager. So, I think this sitting is a desktop thing that spans over many apps.

Comment: do u hear anything when that happens. it could be something to do with an onscreen reading and hearing utility

Comment: I tried all of that. These 'balloon' like hints show every where. That is why I think they are global setting because when I use firefox and move the mouse near a tab at the top, a little balloon comes up with text in it giving the name of the tab (annoying). I can't figure where this setting is defined though. I know on windows where it is, but this does not help me on Linux. I find configuring Linux much harder than windows actually. On linux, things are all over the place, and many configuration tools that seem to do similar things and one does not know what to try.

Comment: Try installing Unsettings MyUnity and Ubuntu Tweak. they provide addition config options

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi The ones you see in Firefox are tooltips and built into the browser. Notice they look different in other browsers.